# set value in foregin key automatically

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

I create two tables

`Table brand`

```
Brand_id(primary key),Brand_name
1                      gucci
```

`Table Product`

```
Product_id, Brand_id(foeign_key),   Product_name
1                                   holand
```

Both table is linked using keys, I want after I update brand name in brand table, the primary key id from brand table automatically insert in product `brand_id`. Is there any possible whenever I enter product name,the foreign key brand_id refelect same like primary key `brand_id`,

i also try to add code for primary key id match the foreign key id, but it doesnt work.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message']=''; 
$mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','demo');
if(isset($_POST["login"])) {
    $product_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $brand_id = 'brand.brand_id';

    $sql ="INSERT INTO product(product_name,brand_id)"
        ."VALUES ('$product_name','brand_id')";     

    if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {

        $_SESSION['message'] =  "Registration successful!
                                                  Added  to the database!";
        header("location:multiple_table.php");
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User could not be added to the database!";      
}

?> 


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>form in Design</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1><?=$_SESSION['brand_name']?></h1>
<form method="POST" action=""><?=$_SESSION['message']?>

<div class="form_input">
<input type="text" name="product_name" placeholder="Enter your Product name"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="login" class="btn-login" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with the `brand` table. How is it supposed to know which `brand_id` to use as the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use the brand whose name is in `$_SESSION['brand_name']`. You can use that to get the `brand_id`.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message']=''; 
$mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','demo');
if(isset($_POST["login"])) {
    $sql ="INSERT INTO product(product_name,brand_id)
           SELECT ?, brand_id
           FROM brand
           WHERE brand_name = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['product_name'], $_SESSION['brand_name']);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $_SESSION['message'] =  "Registration successful!
                                                  Added  to the database!";
        header("location:multiple_table.php");
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User could not be added to the database!";      
}
?>
```

It would be even easier if you put the brand ID into another session variable, like `$_SESSION['brand_id']`. Then you don't need to do a query to get the ID.

You should also learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables. Even using `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` is not as safe from SQL injection.